# Start and Stop entires in MYSQL Logs

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie to MYSQL and I am trying to check where does MYSQL log start and stop entry with timings. I have issue in my application where I get communication link failure at random intervals and trying to check whether MYSQL was down at that time and it restarted after few minutes or not.

MYSQL installation details:

```
innodb_version 5.6.15
protocol_version 10
slave_type_conversions 
version 5.6.15-enterprise-commercial-advanced
version_comment MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os Linux
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"where does MYSQL log start and stop entry with timings."

In the error log, it's formatted with a timestamp.

1st, locate your error log:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_error';
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| log_error     | /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-error.log |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then just tail out the contents:

```
Fri May 02 $ tail -n 100 /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-error.log 
2014-05-02 08:36:35 1024 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
... irrelevant lines ommitted ...
2014-05-02 08:36:45 6473 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Furthermore, you can query the server status variable [uptime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Uptime) to display the number of seconds the server have been up.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'uptime';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Uptime        | 13833 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```